# Android AchartEngine :superposable bar in the same X-axis coordinate

Tags: android, bar-chart, achartengine

I'm using achartEngine library ,and i'm drawing a bar graphe .I would like to have a superposable bars for example if they have the same X coordinates.

**This is what i wont to obtaine :**

[image]

**This is what i'm actualy obtaining :**  If two bars hve the same x ,they are just neighbors.And this is not clear to undertand and specialy if i have more then two bars with the same x.

[image]

**And this is the code i'm using :**

```
public class TruitonAChartEngineActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

private static int SERIES_NR  ; //the number of columns to display,
List<int[]> values = new ArrayList<int[]>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_truiton_achart_engine);
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = getTruitonBarRenderer();
    myChartSettings(renderer);



     Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, getTruitonBarDataset(), renderer, Type.DEFAULT);
        startActivity(intent);

}

 private XYMultipleSeriesDataset getTruitonBarDataset() {
        XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();

        int [] classObject  =new int[] {-70,-56,-45,-80,-47,-55,-80,-50};//,-75};//-85,-35,-45};//Signal strength receiver from each access point

        for (int j=0;j<classObject.length;j++){
        values.add(new int[] { classObject[j]}); //every serie will concern an access point and contain one RSSI
        }

        final int nr = classObject.length;
        ArrayList<String> legendTitles = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int k = 0; k < classObject.length; k++) {
             legendTitles.add("Sales"+k);//every serie will have a legend
        }
        SERIES_NR = classObject.length ;//number of access point
      for (int i = 0; i < SERIES_NR; i++) {//Loop for every series
            CategorySeries series = new CategorySeries(legendTitles.get(i));
            int[] v = values.get(i);
            int seriesLength = v.length;
            dataset.addSeries(series.toXYSeries());

                       for (int k = 0; k < seriesLength; k++) {
                 Log.i("STOOP SERIES_NR",SERIES_NR+"");
                 Log.i("STOOP ii",i+"");
                 Log.i("STOOP",k+"");
                 Log.i("STOOP",v[k]+"");
                 Log.i("STOOP",v[k] / 10+"");

                switch (v[k] / 10){
                case -8 :
                    //series.add(classObject[k]);
                    if (v[k] %10 == 0)
                        //series.add(40);
                    {XYSeries tempSerie = dataset.getSeriesAt(i);
                    tempSerie.add(i, 40);
                    }
                    else 
                    //series.add(40 - v[k] %10);
                    {XYSeries tempSerie = dataset.getSeriesAt(i);
                    tempSerie.add(i, 40 - v[k] %10);
                    }   

                    break;
                case -7 :
                    //series.add(classObject[k]);
                    if (v[k] %10 == 0)
                        {
                        XYSeries tempSerie = dataset.getSeriesAt(i);
                      tempSerie.add(i, 50);
                        tempSerie.addAnnotation("text *** "+i, 0, 50);

                        }

                    else
                    //series.add(50 - v[k] %10);
                        {XYSeries tempSerie = dataset.getSeriesAt(i);
                        tempSerie.add(i, 7.5,50 - v[k] %10);
                //  series.toXYSeries().add(7.5,50 - v[k] %10);
                        }

                    break;
                case -6 :
                    //series.add(classObject[k]);
                    if (v[k] %10 == 0)
                        //series.add(60);
                    {XYSeries tempSerie = dataset.getSeriesAt(i);
                    tempSerie.add(i, 60);

                    }
                    else
                    //series.add(60 - v[k] %10);
                    {XYSeries tempSerie = dataset.getSeriesAt(i);
                    tempSerie.add(i, 60 - v[k] %10);

                    }

                    break;

                case -5 :
                    //series.add(classObject[k]);
                    if (v[k] %10 == 0)
                        //series.add(70);
                    {XYSeries tempSerie = dataset.getSeriesAt(i);
                    tempSerie.add(i, 70);

                    }
                    else
                    //series.add(70 - v[k] %10);
                    {XYSeries tempSerie = dataset.getSeriesAt(i);
                    tempSerie.add(i, 70 - v[k] %10);

                    }

                    break;
                case -4 :
                    //series.add(classObject[k]);
                    if (v[k] %10 == 0)
                        //series.add(80);
                    {XYSeries tempSerie = dataset.getSeriesAt(i);
                    tempSerie.add(i, 80);

                    }

                    else
                    {XYSeries tempSerie = dataset.getSeriesAt(i);
                    tempSerie.add(i, 80 - v[k] %10);
                    tempSerie.addAnnotation("text"+i, i, 80 - v[k] %10);

                    }


                    break;
                case -3 :
                    //series.add(classObject[k]);
                    if (v[k] %10 == 0)
                    {XYSeries tempSerie = dataset.getSeriesAt(i);
                    tempSerie.add(i, 90);

                    }
                    else
                    //series.add(90 - v[k] %10);
                    {XYSeries tempSerie = dataset.getSeriesAt(i);
                    tempSerie.add(i, 90 - v[k] %10);

                    }

                    break;


                }


           }



        }
        return dataset;
    }


public XYMultipleSeriesRenderer getTruitonBarRenderer() {
    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    renderer.setAxisTitleTextSize(10);
    renderer.setChartTitleTextSize(20);
    renderer.setLabelsTextSize(10);
    renderer.setLegendTextSize(10);
    renderer.setMargins(new int[] { 30, 40, 15, 0 });
    int randomColor = Color.rgb((int)(Math.random() * 255), (int)(Math.random() * 255), (int)Math.random() * 255);
    for (int k = 0; k < 8; k++)
    {
        SimpleSeriesRenderer r = new SimpleSeriesRenderer();
        r.setColor(Color.rgb((int)(Math.random() * 255), (int)(Math.random() * 255), (int)Math.random() * 255));
        renderer.addSeriesRenderer(r);
    }


    return renderer;
}

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
private void myChartSettings(XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer) {
    renderer.setChartTitle("Wifi Channels");
    renderer.setXAxisMin(1);
    renderer.setXAxisMax(14);
    renderer.setYAxisMin(30);
    renderer.setYAxisMax(90);
    renderer.addXTextLabel(1, "1");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(2, "2");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(3, "3");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(4, "4");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(5, "5");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(6, "6");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(7, "7");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(8, "8");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(9, "9");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(10, "10");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(11, "11");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(12, "12");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(13, "13");
    renderer.addXTextLabel(14, "14");

    renderer.addYTextLabel(0, "");
    renderer.addYTextLabel(30, "-90");
    renderer.addYTextLabel(40, "-80");
    renderer.addYTextLabel(50, "-70");
    renderer.addYTextLabel(60, "-60");
    renderer.addYTextLabel(70, "-50");
    renderer.addYTextLabel(80, "-40");
    renderer.addYTextLabel(90, "-30");
    renderer.addYTextLabel(100, "");
    renderer.setPanEnabled(true, true);
    renderer.setZoomEnabled(true, true);



    renderer.setApplyBackgroundColor(true);
    renderer.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
    renderer.setBarSpacing(0.5);
    renderer.setXTitle("Canal du WiFi");
    renderer.setYTitle("Puissance du signal[dbm]");
    renderer.setShowGrid(true);
    renderer.setGridColor(Color.GRAY);
    renderer.setXLabels(0); // sets the number of integer labels to appear
  renderer.setXLabels((int) 0.5);//25
    renderer.setYLabels(10);
    renderer.setBarWidth(10);// bar width

}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.truiton_achart_engine, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
    // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
    // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
    int id = item.getItemId();
    if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
        return true;
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}



}
```

Thank you for helping.

Comment: Try    Intent intent = ChartFactory.getBarChartIntent(this, getTruitonBarDataset(), renderer, Type.STACKED);
        startActivity(intent);